# Return only matching subdocs with Mongo aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema with subdocs.

```
// Schema
var company = {
  _id: ObjectId,
  publish: Boolean,
  divisions: {
    employees: [ObjectId]
  }
};
```

I need to find all the subdocs (divisions) that match my query. It appears that I have to use 2 matches - one to filter out initial docs and a second one to filter out the matching subdocs from the resulting $unwind operation. Is there a more efficient way?

```
// Query
this.aggregate({
    $match: {
    'publish': 1,
    'divisions.employees': new ObjectId(userid)
    }
  }, {
    $unwind: '$divisions'
  }, {
    $match: {
      'divisions.employees': new ObjectId(userid)
    }
  }
```

I found this [ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-828) but I am unsure this does what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing both matches is the right thing here. You could eliminate the first match stage and just unwind, but having an initial $match allows you to narrow down the pipeline to exactly those documents that will produce at least one output document (i.e. those documents for which `publish : true` and some `employees` ObjectId matches the given ObjectId). You will be able to use indexes, like an index on `{ publish : 1, divisions.employees : 1 }`, to perform the first match stage quickly.

However, you should ask yourself why you are using the aggregation pipeline here and if it is appropriate. Will you commonly be querying for a given employee that's part of a company with `publish : 1`? Is this one of the main queries for your use case? If it's infrequent or not critical then the aggregation is a good way to do it. Otherwise, you should reconsider the schema. You could make this query easy with a schema like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId,
    "publish" : Boolean,
    "company" : (unique identifier, possibly a String or ObjectId)
}
```

that models employees as documents and denormalizes company information into the employee document. Then your query is as easy as

db.employees.find({ "_id" : ObjectId(userid), "publish" : true })

which will be much quicker than the aggregation (not that the aggregation will be slow; this is just relatively quicker). I'm not telling you to do it this way - use your own knowledge of your use case to make the right call.

Comment: Thanks - I do not aggregation as my real code is considerably more complex. So the most efficient way you suggest is to maintain the `division.employee` query in both matches, just add an index? I wasn't sure if I should just have the `division.employee` in both or just the second.

Comment: I think it's best in both. The first $match is your opportunity to use an index and make the next steps process as few documents as possible, while the condition is necessary in the second $match to get the correct results.